# System Design: multiple client updating same table

Tags: architecture

I came across this interview question and thought what are the views of community here :

> There are 100000 vending machines all around the world which need to
> update a database about maintenance  activities like restocking or any
> technical failure. The update happens at midnight for all the
> machines. A batch system runs after the update and creates work orders
> for the maintenance  task. Do you see a problem in this design?

It is a very abstract question but would like to know the suggestion of community here.

My thoughts / or cross questions would be ( which are quite
generic):

1. Recovery from failure in case db goes down . Write
   contention , depending on how big records are table pages might be
   locked.
2. If there is a time out happening , what does client do send
   request again?
3. server can become very busy processing these requests and other clients HTTP requests can start lining up.
4. Dependency of update process . Does update process
   keeps on polling the db ?

Note: I know it is not a well thought question from stack overflow perspective but I want to understand how to tackle such questions.

Comment: By the way, I thought the thoughts you had were really good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to understand how to tackle such questions.

It all comes down to your mental model, and how you learn to apply it in different scenarios.  The way I tackle technical scenarios/questions like this is by using some fuzzy combination of the following:

1. **Making sure I understand the problem**.  Often I'll do myself a diagram to help understand it visually.
2. **Make sure I understand the actual question**.  Don't lose sight of what's actually being asked of you - don't get distracted.  In this example it'd be easy to look at 'vending machines all around the world' and 'update a database' whilst there is no mention of how these actually connect.  "OMG, use a REST API you newbs!"... which *might* be a better solution, but that's the answer to a different question.
3. **Decompose things** and considering them through different "lenses"...
4. **Expansion & Mental walkthrough** - Expansion is all about taking the basics and fleshing them out.  The mental walkthrough is where you try to make it more real in your head and start stepping through them can help identify flaws.

For interview questions I guess you'll typically do #1 & 2, then 3 or 4 in any order - it will depend on the situation.  Again, for interview questions, I find the two parts of #4 typically happen at once.

**Lenses**

My use of the word "lenses" here is generic - simply a way of looking at something in different ways.  Some specific domains have specific terms for these - such as [Views and perspectives](https://www.viewpoints-and-perspectives.info/home/perspectives/) found in architecture.

Not all of these apply to your example question; they're a wider set for all kinds of situations.  Which ones to use is usually obvious - at least will should become more intuitive as you gain more experience.

- **Assumptions** - What assumptions are being made and how safe are they?  Sometimes the point of an interview question is to find a flawed assumption and explain it.   In the real-world people make assumptions all the time - sometimes they are flawed, and sometimes they *were* correct but situations change overtime which can render them flawed.
- **Dependencies** - what dependencies exist and how are these relevant?  These might be explicit and obvious, or implied (more subtle).  They might exist at runtime, or be inherent in the structure of the thing.  Dependencies will come up through most of the following lenses too.
- **Relationships** - how are things logically connected?  E.g. Are things tightly-coupled where they should be loosely-coupled?
- **Ins and Outs** - What are the various inputs and outputs?
- **Runtime** - What's happening when stuff executes?  Where does it execute?
- **Design & Build** - are there any implications that affect how the solution is built?  Or, in the other way around: does the design / build approach have implications for how the solution is deployed and run?
- **Deployment** - How is the solution physically arranged?  What's the process for getting it there?
- **Connectivity** - How do things communicate?  How do they discover each other?
- **Security** - Public / internet facing or private or both?  How is authentication and authorization dealt with?
- **SDLC** - The lifecycle of designing, building, testing, deploying, operating, modifying/maintaining, upgrading and decommissioning the solution.
- **Architecture** - What's the overall architecture - does it fit into any recognizable one, and what does that tell you?   Basic concepts like logical layers and physical tiers can be good mental starting points for evaluation.
- **Scenarios** - Where you mentally test things by imagining "what if?"  E.g. system/component failure.
- **Back to Basic's** - It's easy to get caught up in the detail, sometimes you need to go back to the basics and fundamentals, work from first principles, etc.

A lot of these overlap, for example deployment has one foot in the design & build area (how things are packaged up for deployment), and another in the runtime (what happens once it is deployed).

**Further Reading: "Cheat Sheet" Approach**

For me, there's a lot of synergy between answering these types of interview question and real-world problems - and how you approach them.

The list above is a bunch of things you might use to attack a problem, but I have also developed a similar approach in terms of how I learnt architecture - and how I dealt with various day-to-day scenarios that you get flung into as a solution architect, where you either need to switch context really fast (going from one meeting to another), or look for completeness (e.g. reviewing designs).

In short, you can develop a "cheat sheet" for reference, which works in two ways:

1. Development of the cheat sheet is an act of (self-directed) learning in itself.
2. The cheat sheet provides a point of quick reference.

I used this approach mainly when I was a junior architect.

My original write up is on my blog here: [Architectural Cheat Sheet (v3.0 – 2009)](https://morphological.wordpress.com/2016/07/04/architectural-cheat-sheet-v3-0-2009/), and more recently I've been doing workshops and [meet-ups](https://morphological.wordpress.com/2021/02/26/geekle-meet-up-feb-2021-apis-and-microservices-architecture-cheat-sheets/) on it.